# How to get the remaining page size using syncfusion pdf

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

i am creating pdf using synfusion pdf plugin for xamarin forms and what happenes if i print my pdf then there is many remaining space on the page so how i can get that remaining space of pdf page using syncfusion pdf [image: please see this screenshot the area in the red box is remaining how i can get this area]

Comment: What would you like to display in the remaining space?

Comment: i want next question to be start from next page currently the next question is starting from this empty space i just want to get this remaining space through code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the blank space region in the page of PDF document by using PdfLayoutResult. Please refer the below code snippet for more details,

C#:

```
//Create a text element with the text and font
PdfTextElement textElement = new PdfTextElement(text, font);
PdfLayoutFormat layoutFormat = new PdfLayoutFormat();
layoutFormat.Layout = PdfLayoutType.Paginate;

//Draw the paragraph
PdfLayoutResult result = textElement.Draw(page, new RectangleF(0, 0, 
page.GetClientSize().Width, page.GetClientSize().Height), layoutFormat);

//Get the blank space of PDF using PdfLayoutResult and page height 
float blankSpaceHeight = page.GetClientSize().Height - result.Bounds.Bottom;
```

We have created the sample for the same which can be downloaded from below link,

[Sample to get the remaining page size of PDF document](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/GettingStarted-453649822)

Answer (score 0):

We can get the blank page by loop pixel from last line page to first line page and compare color with White color. If different from than white color then we return at this position
For example:

```
static float GetHeightFromPdfPage(Stream streamData, int pageIndex)
{
    // Convert last page to image
    var image = ConvertPageToImage(streamData, pageIndex);
    // Loop from last positionx to first position of image
    // Return if detect any color in (A, B, G) is different from than white color
    for (int y = image.Height - 1; y >= 0; y --)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
        {
            var colorPixel = image.GetPixel(x, y);
            if (colorPixel.A != System.Drawing.Color.White.A || colorPixel.B != System.Drawing.Color.White.B || colorPixel.G != System.Drawing.Color.White.G)
            {
                return y;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static Bitmap ConvertPageToImage(Stream streamData, int pageIndex)
{
    var loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument(streamData);
    var page = loadedDocument.Pages[pageIndex];

    PdfRenderer pdfExportImage = new PdfRenderer();
    pdfExportImage.Load(streamData);
    var skBitmap = pdfExportImage.ExportAsImage(pageIndex, page.Size, true);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        skBitmap.Encode(ms, SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
        return new Bitmap(ms);
    }
}
```